# Android expansion file creation ZIP or JOBB?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am creating the expansion file for my apk which exceeds 100mb size.

how should i create an expansion archive using JOBB from sdk or default windows archive file..

and any working sample project link will also be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally 
I ended up using the compression less zip archive.
it can easily be created by winrar using compression method "store"

if you just want to store the media/files in expansion file simply use zip files.
note:you may use zip align from android sdk to make your file memory optimized.

Answer (score 4):

That's right, look at what the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) says:

**Reading media files from a ZIP**

If you're using your expansion files to store media files, a ZIP file still allows you to use Android media playback calls that provide offset and length controls (such as MediaPlayer.setDataSource() and SoundPool.load()). In order for this to work, you must not perform additional compression on the media files when creating the ZIP packages. For example, when using the zip tool, you should use the -n option to specify the file suffixes that should not be compressed:

Example using Linux command line:

```
zip -r -0 main.1.com.my.pkg.obb media_files/
```